# paw auto refresh on save or every x seconds via time interval

Tags: paw-app

anyone an idea if this is somehow possible?
I tried around with different methods but couldn't get anything working...
Maybe it is somehow possible via the script editor or in combination with a watcher client?

thanks!

Comment: That's something we wanted to add for a long time, but it still isn't there. We will be adding this at some point for sure...

Comment: Just make sure it won't stop unless set somehow on error. if it doesn't return a 200 and you stop the refresh and would be frustrating ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Agreed! Will keep that in mind!

Comment: @MichaMazaheri *cough :P